# What is the purpose of the "GET" methods second parameter?

Tags: java, preferences

I was reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) . It looks not very intuitive to me that all `get` methods have two arguments . E.g.

```
abstract String get(String key, String def)
Returns the value associated with the specified key in this preference node.
```

**It doesn't make sense. Why do we need the second argument?**

**I know when we feed the second argument with a value, that value gets assigned unless it's null.** So okay one purpose would be to initialize a `key-value` pair. But I can also initialize the key value pair with `put` .

Here is a sample code

```
preferences.put("testKey", "testValue"); 
System.out.println(preferences.get("testKey", null)); // returns testValue 
System.out.println(preferences.get("testKey", "NOT NULL")); // returns testValue 
System.out.println(preferences.get("testKey", "WHATEVER")); // returns testValue
```

So I just don't see a good use of the second   parameter. I'm sure there are uses. So, why do we have that second parameter in Preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument is a default value (for when the preference isn't set at all). Without that argument, you would get `null` for an undefined property.

Comment: Oh . . . .sorry, I think I'm getting it . This is just in case something happens  that would be the default

Comment: Okay, so if your program sets a `null` to some key value pair , then that would be the last resort . Makes sense now